# GET requests in CouchDB map function

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

Is it possible to make GET requests to the external Web service using GET requests in view's map function? E.g. I have an classification service with REST API. And I want to classify document in map function by calling(not async) API function. Is it possible to implement in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with default javascript query server. But if you enable the [native erlang query server](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/query-servers.html#native-erlang-query-server) you can execute arbitrary code including making http requests.  For example you can do this

```
%% Map Function
 fun({Doc}) ->
     <<K,_/binary>> = proplists:get_value(<<"_rev">>, Doc, null),
     V = proplists:get_value(<<"_id">>, Doc, null),

     %% Making the http request

     {ok,{Status,Headers,Body}} = httpc:request("some url"),

     %% do some stuff with the response and then emit

     Emit(<<K>>, V)

end.
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of Erlang I've used Python. But the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :) Didn't know you could do that in python too.